# Persistent display of updated rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

We have a SQL Server database table that's constantly updated throughout the day. I wish to have a monitor window showing most recently updated/added rows in this SQL Server table, without having to go back and run SELECT statements every 15 mins or so. I'm not sure if this can be achieved in SQL Server logs or through other 3rd party applications. Please point out a way.

Comment: You could make a page with AJAX doing some [long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29#Ajax_with_long_polling).

Comment: Create Triggers which can log to file or a table.

Comment: Why don't you want to re-query the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create trigger which can log to file or database like the one in [here](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2005/log-file-trigger/)

Comment: A trigger is a good response, so long as you want your data that granular. If your alternative is to run a select every 15 mins, that may be better, because it will have significantly less of a performance impact on your server if you are regularly inserting/updating more often than that.

Comment: @Sethcran Exactly, but you never know when KLI wanted to have a look at the data, unless query based on time.

Comment: Thanks @Phani. I will try to implement the trigger and log-into-file idea.

Comment: Followed Phani's link to set up trigger and log into file. Had to use BareTail in windows to display log file on top of screen. Exactly what I wanted! Thanks.